# Comprobar si existe una palabra en un arreglo de strings en c++

Tags: c++, array, busqueda

Quiero hacer un programa que compruebe si una palabra existe en un arreglo ya creado, el programa funciona bien cuando la palabra si existe, pero cuando no existe me marca el error Segmentation fault (core dumped).
No se por qué ocurre este error, estoy usando una bandera de tipo carácter para marcar 'V' cuando encuentra la palabra y si no la encuentra devuelve 'F'.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//arreglo
string lista[] = {"papas", "leche", "huevos", "harina", "jugo"};
char buscar(string); 
int main(){
   string palabra;
   char validar;
   cout<<"Palabra: "; cin>>palabra;
   validar = buscar(palabra);
   if(validar == 'V')
      cout<<"La palabra existe";
   else if(validar == 'F')
      cout<<"Palabra inexistente";
   return 0;
}
//funcion para comprobar si existe la palabra
char buscar(string pal){
   int i = 0;
   char band;
   while(pal != lista[i] && i<5){
       i++;
   }
   if(pal == lista[i])
       return band = 'V';
   else
       return band = 'F';
}
```

Comment: Una búsqueda en Google no le hace mal a nadie :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303821/how-to-check-if-string-is-in-array-of-strings

Comment: Perdón, si busqué pero supongo que cómo estaba en ingles, no me salió

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
if( pal == lista[i] )
```

Llegas ahí al terminar tu bucle `while( )`, una de cuyas condiciones es

```
i < 5
```

Es decir, al salir del bucle sin encontrar la palabra, **`i == 5`**. Y ahí tienes tu problema: estarías intentando acceder a `lista[5]`, que no existe.

Simplemente, modifica un poco el `if( )` posterior:

```
if( i > 4 ) {
    return 'F';
}

return 'V';
```